# Send a file from one pc to another pc where owncloud is installed

Tags: python, cloud, iot

I want to send a file from a pc to another machine where owncloud is installed

```
import owncloud

oc = owncloud.Client('http://192.168.xx.xx/')

oc.login('username', 'password')

oc.mkdir('testdir')

oc.put_file('testdir/remotefile.txt', 'deno.txt',remote_user=True)

print('success')
```

The error is as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "cloud.py", line 5, in
>   
>       oc.login('xxxx', 'xxxx')   File "/home/yash/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/owncloud/owncloud.py",
>   line 354, in login
>       self._update_capabilities()   File "/home/yash/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/owncloud/owncloud.py",
>   line 1795, in _update_capabilities
>       'capabilities'   File "/home/yash/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/owncloud/owncloud.py",
>   line 1649, in _make_ocs_request
>       res = self._session.request(method, self.url + path, **attributes)   File
>   "/home/yash/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
>   line 533, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/home/yash/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
>   line 646, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/home/yash/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
>   line 516, in send
>       raise ConnectionError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.xx.xx', port=80): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /ocs/v1.php/cloud/capabilities (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
>   Connection refused',))

Comment: Your server is not setup so the other side of a new connection is not ready to receive your request. Seems so in your traceback.

Comment: Owncloud is running on the other side. What should be done to setup server??

Comment: You are using 192.168.x.x so this address should be your server's IP. I don't know about owncloud but it must has something like `owncloud.Server` to run.